# Excel logical numeric evaluation

Tags: excel-formula

So I have a sheet where I am assigning levels to individuals based on their training, IE: Level 4 SME, Level 3 trained and can train others, level 2 trained, and level 1 untrained. For each shift, I want at least 2 level 2 individuals if so readiness is 100% anything above that is over percentage(which is fine) but anything less I want it to be less than 100%. **I am trying to do this with formulas but it is not working the way I want.**

[Table Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk9Z3.png)

[Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1YvQ.png)

The above example would show more than 100% becuse there is more then two people at level 2 I wish there was a way to loop in excel to allow for me to increment and number for every count of 2.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:E2,">=2")>=2,">=100%","not ready")
```

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed formula]

you can do a certain amount of looping in the UI with the LAMBDA function, if you have Office 365, although I'm not clear as to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTIF(B2:E2,">=2") * 0.5` --> format as percent

[image]